# c# How to make smooth arc region using graphics path

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls

I'm trying to make a label control with rounded sides. 
Here is my code in OnPaint() overridden method in myclass inherited from Label.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, GradientColor1, GradientColor2, 90);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width, this.Height)));

        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp.AddArc(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Height, this.Height)), 90, 180);
            gp.AddLine(new Point(this.Height / 2, 0), new Point(this.Width - (this.Height / 2), 0));
            gp.AddArc(new Rectangle(new Point(this.Width - this.Height, 0), new Size(this.Height, this.Height)), -90, 180);
            gp.CloseFigure();

            this.Region = new Region(gp);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

The problem is that it is not smoothing the curve on the sides and showing the glitches.
Here is the screenshot of the control :

[image]

Comment: You can't anti-alias a region.

Comment: Do you really need to change the region? For a round label, it seems it's enough to fill your round background and there is no need to change region. This way you can fill the shape smoothly.

Comment: To spell out Reza's point: Label supports Transparency reasonably well. Just don't try to make it overlap different controls!

Comment: @Reza I need to change the region to make it round. If you are having any cross over then please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can't anti-alias the region, so you have to use graphic's FillPath method in order for the drawing to be anti-aliased

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.Aqua, Color.Blue, 90);

            using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gp.AddArc(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Height, this.Height)), 90, 180);
                gp.AddLine(new Point(this.Height / 2, 0), new Point(this.Width - (this.Height / 2), 0));
                gp.AddArc(new Rectangle(new Point(this.Width - this.Height, 0), new Size(this.Height, this.Height)), -90, 180);
                gp.CloseFigure();

                e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
```

If you really need to change the region I guess you would have to use a slightly bigger region then the one used for the drawing:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.Aqua, Color.Blue, 90);

        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            AddRoundedRectangle(gp, new Point(1, 1), new Size(this.Size.Width - 2, Size.Height - 2));
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);
        }

        using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            AddRoundedRectangle(gp, new Point(0, 0), this.Size);
            this.Region = new Region(gp);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private void AddRoundedRectangle(GraphicsPath gp, Point upperLeft, Size size)
    {
        gp.AddArc(new Rectangle(upperLeft, new Size(size.Height, size.Height)), 90, 180);
        gp.AddLine(new Point(size.Height / 2 , upperLeft.Y), new Point(size.Width - (size.Height / 2), upperLeft.Y));
        gp.AddArc(new Rectangle(new Point(size.Width - size.Height, upperLeft.Y), new Size(size.Height, size.Height)), -90, 180);
        gp.CloseFigure();
    }
```

The second option has the advantage of affecting events like MouseHover but may run into problems of you seeing the region's "border".