# Winforms: Smooth the rounded edges for panel

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, panel

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/3790451/Creating-a-Rounded-Panel-Control.htm) in order to create a rounded panel. The code in the tutorial is in vb but I was able to convert it to C# so here is my code:

```
    public class SPanel : Panel
{
    Pen pen;
    float penWidth = 2.0f;
    int _edge = 20;
    Color _borderColor = Color.White;
    public int Edge
    {
        get
        {
            return _edge;
        }
        set
        {
            _edge = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _borderColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _borderColor = value;
            pen = new Pen(_borderColor, penWidth);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public SPanel()
    {
        pen = new Pen(_borderColor, penWidth);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        ExtendedDraw(e);
        //DrawBorder(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void ExtendedDraw(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        path.StartFigure();
        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddArc(GetLeftUpper(Edge), 180, 90);
        path.AddLine(Edge, 0, Width - Edge, 0);
        path.AddArc(GetRightUpper(Edge), 270, 90);
        path.AddLine(Width, Edge, Width, Height - Edge);
        path.AddArc(GetRightLower(Edge), 0, 90);
        path.AddLine(Width - Edge, Height, Edge, Height);
        path.AddArc(GetLeftLower(Edge), 90, 90);
        path.AddLine(0, Height - Edge, 0, Edge);
        path.CloseFigure();

        Region = new Region(path);
    }

    Rectangle GetLeftUpper(int e)
    {
        return new Rectangle(0, 0, e, e);
    }
    Rectangle GetRightUpper(int e)
    {
        return new Rectangle(Width - e, 0, e, e);
    }
    Rectangle GetRightLower(int e)
    {
        return new Rectangle(Width - e, Height - e, e, e);
    }
    Rectangle GetLeftLower(int e)
    {
        return new Rectangle(0, Height - e, e, e);
    }

    void DrawSingleBorder(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.DrawArc(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, Edge, Edge), 180, 90);
        graphics.DrawArc(pen, new Rectangle(Width - Edge -1, -1, Edge, Edge), 270, 90);
        graphics.DrawArc(pen, new Rectangle(Width - Edge - 1, Height - Edge - 1, Edge, Edge), 0, 90);
        graphics.DrawArc(pen, new Rectangle(0, Height - Edge - 1, Edge, Edge), 90, 90);

        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0.0F, 0.0F, Width - 1, Height - 1);
    }

    void DrawBorder(Graphics graphics)
    {
        DrawSingleBorder(graphics);
    }
 }
```

I did not use the border however the result is the same. Here is a ss:

[image]

I thought smoothing with anti alias would do the trick but I guess i was wrong. The question is how can I smooth the edges?

Comment: You cant anti-alias a region. So use Graphics.FillPath for the drawing to be anti-aliased

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878184/c-sharp-how-to-make-smooth-arc-region-using-graphics-path

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve this by following [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38436/Extended-Graphics-Rounded-rectangles-Font-metrics). I just downloaded the sample project and created a new panel. Copied what he had on Form's onpaint to new panel's onpaint and now I have smooth edges.

```
public class SPanel : Panel
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.FillRoundedRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 10, 10, this.Width - 40, this.Height - 60, 10);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(
            Color.White
            );
        g.FillRoundedRectangle(brush, 12, 12, this.Width - 44, this.Height - 64, 10);
        g.DrawRoundedRectangle(new Pen(ControlPaint.Light(Color.White, 0.00f)), 12, 12, this.Width - 44, this.Height - 64, 10);
        g.FillRoundedRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 12, 12 + ((this.Height - 64) / 2), this.Width - 44, (this.Height - 64)/2, 10);
    }
}
```

Here is his GraphicsExtension class if link ever get broken.

```
static class GraphicsExtension
{
    private static GraphicsPath GenerateRoundedRectangle(
        this Graphics graphics, 
        RectangleF rectangle, 
        float radius)
    {
        float diameter;
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        if (radius <= 0.0F)
        {
            path.AddRectangle(rectangle);
            path.CloseFigure();
            return path;
        }
        else
        {
            if (radius >= (Math.Min(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height)) / 2.0)
                return graphics.GenerateCapsule(rectangle);
            diameter = radius * 2.0F;
            SizeF sizeF = new SizeF(diameter, diameter);
            RectangleF arc = new RectangleF(rectangle.Location, sizeF);
            path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90);
            arc.X = rectangle.Right - diameter;
            path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);
            arc.Y = rectangle.Bottom - diameter;
            path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);
            arc.X = rectangle.Left;
            path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90);
            path.CloseFigure();
        }
        return path;
    }
    private static GraphicsPath GenerateCapsule(
        this Graphics graphics, 
        RectangleF baseRect)
    {
        float diameter;
        RectangleF arc;
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        try
        {
            if (baseRect.Width > baseRect.Height)
            {
                diameter = baseRect.Height;
                SizeF sizeF = new SizeF(diameter, diameter);
                arc = new RectangleF(baseRect.Location, sizeF);
                path.AddArc(arc, 90, 180);
                arc.X = baseRect.Right - diameter;
                path.AddArc(arc, 270, 180);
            }
            else if (baseRect.Width < baseRect.Height)
            {
                diameter = baseRect.Width;
                SizeF sizeF = new SizeF(diameter, diameter);
                arc = new RectangleF(baseRect.Location, sizeF);
                path.AddArc(arc, 180, 180);
                arc.Y = baseRect.Bottom - diameter;
                path.AddArc(arc, 0, 180);
            }
            else path.AddEllipse(baseRect);
        }
        catch { path.AddEllipse(baseRect); }
        finally { path.CloseFigure(); }
        return path;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a rounded rectangle specified by a pair of coordinates, a width, a height and the radius 
    /// for the arcs that make the rounded edges.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="brush">System.Drawing.Pen that determines the color, width and style of the rectangle.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Width of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Height of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="radius">The radius of the arc used for the rounded edges.</param>

    public static void DrawRoundedRectangle(
        this Graphics graphics, 
        Pen pen, 
        float x, 
        float y, 
        float width, 
        float height, 
        float radius)
    {
        RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
        GraphicsPath path = graphics.GenerateRoundedRectangle(rectangle, radius);
        SmoothingMode old = graphics.SmoothingMode;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = old;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a rounded rectangle specified by a pair of coordinates, a width, a height and the radius 
    /// for the arcs that make the rounded edges.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="brush">System.Drawing.Pen that determines the color, width and style of the rectangle.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Width of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Height of the rectangle to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="radius">The radius of the arc used for the rounded edges.</param>

    public static void DrawRoundedRectangle(
        this Graphics graphics, 
        Pen pen, 
        int x, 
        int y, 
        int width, 
        int height, 
        int radius)
    {
        graphics.DrawRoundedRectangle(
            pen, 
            Convert.ToSingle(x), 
            Convert.ToSingle(y), 
            Convert.ToSingle(width), 
            Convert.ToSingle(height), 
            Convert.ToSingle(radius));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fills the interior of a rounded rectangle specified by a pair of coordinates, a width, a height
    /// and the radius for the arcs that make the rounded edges.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="brush">System.Drawing.Brush that determines the characteristics of the fill.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Width of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Height of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="radius">The radius of the arc used for the rounded edges.</param>

    public static void FillRoundedRectangle(
        this Graphics graphics, 
        Brush brush, 
        float x, 
        float y, 
        float width, 
        float height, 
        float radius)
    {
        RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
        GraphicsPath path = graphics.GenerateRoundedRectangle(rectangle, radius);
        SmoothingMode old = graphics.SmoothingMode;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = old;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fills the interior of a rounded rectangle specified by a pair of coordinates, a width, a height
    /// and the radius for the arcs that make the rounded edges.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="brush">System.Drawing.Brush that determines the characteristics of the fill.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Width of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Height of the rectangle to fill.</param>
    /// <param name="radius">The radius of the arc used for the rounded edges.</param>

    public static void FillRoundedRectangle(
        this Graphics graphics, 
        Brush brush, 
        int x, 
        int y, 
        int width, 
        int height, 
        int radius)
    {
        graphics.FillRoundedRectangle(
            brush, 
            Convert.ToSingle(x), 
            Convert.ToSingle(y), 
            Convert.ToSingle(width), 
            Convert.ToSingle(height), 
            Convert.ToSingle(radius)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to ``Invalidate()`` the panel on resize events. Otherwise it will make nested borders. Also consider setting ``DoubleBuffered = true`` to improve the resize redraws.

Answer (score 5):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
            int nLeftRect,     // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nTopRect,      // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
            int nRightRect,    // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nBottomRect,   // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
            int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
            int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
        );

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
        }
    }
}
```

I found solution internet and tried and success! Hope help you

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace windowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]

        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
            int nLeftRect,
            int nTopRect,
            int nRightRect,
            int nBottomRect,
            int nWidthEllipse,
            int nHeightEllipse
        );
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Region = Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, panel1.Width, 
            panel1.Height, 30, 30));
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code to edit an answer that is almost 5 years' old and has an accepted answer. Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation of how your answer solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks for showing that we can also use "Region" for the panel's location and size. That way it is easy to create a Form with rounded corners (Form's Region property) and a user defined border.

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to do the same and finally I did this by creating Custom Control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace your.namespace.here
{
public class CustomPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel;

    private Color borderColor = Color.MediumSlateBlue;
    private Color borderFocusColor = Color.HotPink;
    private int borderSize = 2;
    private bool underlinedStyle = false;
    private bool isFocused = false;

    private int borderRadius = 0;


    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set
        {
            borderColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color BorderFocusColor
    {
        get { return borderFocusColor; }
        set { borderFocusColor = value; }
    }

    public int BorderSize
    {
        get { return borderSize; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 1)
            {
                borderSize = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool UnderlinedStyle
    {
        get { return underlinedStyle; }
        set
        {
            underlinedStyle = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return base.ForeColor; }
        set
        {
            base.ForeColor = value;
            panel.ForeColor = value;
        }
    }


    public int BorderRadius
    {
        get { return borderRadius; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                borderRadius = value;
                this.Invalidate();//Redraw control
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics graph = e.Graphics;

        if (borderRadius > 1)//Rounded TextBox
        {
            //-Fields
            var rectBorderSmooth = this.ClientRectangle;
            var rectBorder = Rectangle.Inflate(rectBorderSmooth, -borderSize, -borderSize);
            int smoothSize = borderSize > 0 ? borderSize : 1;

            using (GraphicsPath pathBorderSmooth = GetFigurePath(rectBorderSmooth, borderRadius))
            using (GraphicsPath pathBorder = GetFigurePath(rectBorder, borderRadius - borderSize))
            using (Pen penBorderSmooth = new Pen(this.Parent.BackColor, smoothSize))
            using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
            {
                //-Drawing
                this.Region = new Region(pathBorderSmooth);//Set the rounded region of UserControl
                if (borderRadius > 15) SetTextBoxRoundedRegion();//Set the rounded region of TextBox component
                graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                penBorder.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Center;
                if (isFocused) penBorder.Color = borderFocusColor;

                if (underlinedStyle) //Line Style
                {
                    //Draw border smoothing
                    graph.DrawPath(penBorderSmooth, pathBorderSmooth);
                    //Draw border
                    graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
                    graph.DrawLine(penBorder, 0, this.Height - 1, this.Width, this.Height - 1);
                }
                else //Normal Style
                {
                    //Draw border smoothing
                    graph.DrawPath(penBorderSmooth, pathBorderSmooth);
                    //Draw border
                    graph.DrawPath(penBorder, pathBorder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void SetTextBoxRoundedRegion()
    {
        GraphicsPath pathTxt;


        pathTxt = GetFigurePath(panel.ClientRectangle, borderSize * 2);
        panel.Region = new Region(pathTxt);

        pathTxt.Dispose();
    }
    private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath(Rectangle rect, int radius)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        float curveSize = radius * 2F;

        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }
}
}
```

the output is like:

[image]

Note: this code is only for Custom Panel.

Answer (score -1):

In your code:

```
 private void ExtendedDraw(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.White, Color.White, 90); //here you need your target rectangle

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

    path.StartFigure();
    path.StartFigure();
    path.AddArc(GetLeftUpper(Edge), 180, 90);
    path.AddLine(Edge, 0, Width - Edge, 0);
    path.AddArc(GetRightUpper(Edge), 270, 90);
    path.AddLine(Width, Edge, Width, Height - Edge);
    path.AddArc(GetRightLower(Edge), 0, 90);
    path.AddLine(Width - Edge, Height, Edge, Height);
    path.AddArc(GetLeftLower(Edge), 90, 90);
    path.AddLine(0, Height - Edge, 0, Edge);
    path.CloseFigure();

    e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
}
```

Comment: This line doesn't make sense: `LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.White, Color.White, 90); //here you need your target rectangle`. You should just use a `SolidBrush` if you want to fill something with one color: `var fillBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkCyan);`.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, sorry. the main point is that you need a brush for FillPath

Comment: No worries, just wanted to point it out to avoid confusion over that.

Comment: Result is the same. Nothing changed, in fact you missed 
            Region = new Region(path);
so it does not become rounded.

Comment: Well, sorry something changed. Right lower corner is smoother now but I cannot say the same for  others.

https://s32.postimg.org/9021ayusl/Untitled.png

Answer (score -1):

Mine is an alternative solution that requires no code or pre-paid modules.

Start by creating a round edged container on MS PowerPoint or MS Paint for example (Draw Rectangle with rounded corners, you can even add shadows if you want).

Take a screenshot of it or use snipping tool and save it as a .png; Then go to any online tool to make the background transparent.

Download the new image and use it on a pictureBox on your C# .NET solution and there, you have your own HD rounded background with shadow effects (Use the Anchor and Dock properties to give it the effects and positions that you want on your Form).

Comment: I think using panels is better because than you can add things inside. With a png you are limited to the picture + less responsive.