# Panel Round Edge

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public void DrawRoundRect(Graphics g, Pen p, float X, float Y, float width, float height, float radius)
    {
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddLine(X + radius, Y, X + width - (radius * 2), Y);
        gp.AddArc(X + width - (radius * 2), Y, radius * 2, radius * 2, 270, 90);
        gp.AddLine(X + width, Y + radius, X + width, Y + height - (radius * 2));
        gp.AddArc(X + width - (radius * 2), Y + height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 0, 90);
        gp.AddLine(X + width - (radius * 2), Y + height, X + radius, Y + height);
        gp.AddArc(X, Y + height - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2, 90, 90);
        gp.AddLine(X, Y + height - (radius * 2), X, Y + radius);
        gp.AddArc(X, Y, radius * 2, radius * 2, 180, 90);
        gp.CloseFigure();
        g.DrawPath(p, gp);
    }

    private void _pnlLogIn_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics v = e.Graphics;
        DrawRoundRect(v, Pens.Blue, e.ClipRectangle.Left, e.ClipRectangle.Top, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1, 10);
        //Without rounded corners
        //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, e.ClipRectangle.Left, e.ClipRectangle.Top, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Hello, What is wrong with my code. My panel has already a round edge but the border of the rectangular panel remains. What code should i add or revise? thank you..

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuHXh.png)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean sir about ovverriding it on paint

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I already added the screenshot sir

Comment: Don't use e.ClipRectangle.  Use the Panel's.ClientRectangle.

Comment: Try to add some `Padding` to the panel: `panel.Padding = new Padding(5, 0, 5, 0)`. Adjust the `left` and `right` as you need.

Comment: maybe that can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632035/winforms-smooth-the-rounded-edges-for-panel

Comment: @jonathana i dont really get what they are talking in there..

Comment: @LarsTech what do you mean? should i change the e.Clip to 
panelname.ClientRectangle???

Answer (score 3):

Set your panel **region** to Graphics path.

In your code posted, do it after you call `DrawPath` in `DrawRoundRect` method.

Something like this:

```
_pnlLogIn.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(gp);
```

After I do above code change, I see my window as shown below.

I tried with bit bigger radius (40)..

[image]

Comment: sir may i ask where to set the panel region? is it in the panel_Paint or the method that i made?

Comment: and how will i do that?

Comment: Put it in DrawRoundRect function after  g.DrawPath(p, gp);

Comment: the panel and my components become invisible

Comment: after adding _pnlLogIn.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(gp); after g.draw

Comment: Set the backcolor of panel in your constructor, as said "_pnlLogIn.BackColor = Color.White;"

Comment: For my sample it is working fine. can you do one last favor? Can you call "_pnlLogIn.BackColor = Color.White;", just before setting the region

Comment: still the same sir :/

Comment: How you are adding your controls to your panel? Is it some user control adding to pannel or just controls form toolbox

Comment: well i just use the panel, because our system interface design has a white panel that has the like that i posted.. so the controls of the components are basically coded :/

Comment: Is it possible to call the coded controls after setting the region?

Comment: about controls, do you mean (example: my panel has button.. did you mean about button controls on that panel? like when i click it what will happen on it?)

Comment: No. drawing controls on panel if you do manually (I mean if not from toolbox)

Comment: Added image of window from my sample.